# map().partitionBy() How many shuffles these 2 commands will do?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Question :

1)
So if i have :

```
SomeRDD = myRDD.map().partitionBy(new hashPartitioner(2))
```

How many shuffles these two commands will make?
Is that 2 shuffles? 1 for the map(), and 1 for the partitionBy()? or 1 ?
It's not yet clear to me...

Answer (score 3):

A map does not cause a shuffle. It is a narrow transformation, i.e. the function (which is missing in your code sample) would be called on each element individually.

A shuffle would be called when you need to access data from different partitions (i.e. a wide transformation). When you do a partitionBy you tell spark that it needs to repartition according to your request and therefore may cause a shuffle.